# Does it matter which field is used to perform a JOIN on for performance?

Tags: sql, join, select

Will the order of the field on my join statement ever matter? Does this improve performance?

For example,

```
Select * 
from TABLEA
left join TABLEB on TABLEA.NUM_0 = TABLEB.NUM_0
```

vs.

```
Select * 
from TABLEA
left join TABLEB on TABLEB.NUM_0 = TABLEA.NUM_0
```

Does the order of the on field actually matter? This same question can be for multiple and statements for joins.

Thank you.

Comment: When clear, this will be a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: I'm using SQL Server and fixed my question. GMB was able to answer it in the later part of his answer. Thanks.

Comment: This shows no research about what queries mean or about performance. Re there being a result difference, what is an answer but a rewrite of the meaning of queries? You don't need us for that. Ask about where your expectations are not met & why or where you are stuck in a presentation trying to answer this yourself & why. Also your description is still not clear, although your example shows a certain sense of reordering. Order of function, logical operator & JOIN operands & of JOINs are all faqs. So is basics of performance. PS Please clarify via edits, not comments. PS Ask 1 question per post.

Comment: See [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) to learn to use @x to notify one non-sole non-poster commenter x re a comment.

Answer (score 1):

As for these two join conditions:

```
on TABLEA.NUM_0 = TABLEB.NUM
on TABLEB.NUM_0 = TABLEA.NUM
```

The conditions are not the same (you are using different columns in both tables), so the queries are different, and potentially produce different results.

Now, if you actually meant:

```
on TABLEA.NUM_0 = TABLEB.NUM
on TABLEB.NUM   = TABLEA.NUM_0
```

Here the conditions are equivalent. Does inverting the operands make a difference for the database? No. In arithmetics, equality is a *commutative* operation - so is it for databases. The query planner understands that, and regards both expressions as the very same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you meant the two ON clauses to be the same, then no, it doesn't matter.  The SQL actually gets "compiled" into an execution plan where those types of differences won't matter.

Comment: There is no `where` clause?

Comment: Sorry, ON clause.  Same idea.  The order doesn't matter once compiled into an execution plan.

Comment: answer updated.